# Unconvertable Characters Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am receiving an "Unconvertable character" error in my XSL transform. The goal of the XSL is to remove the namespace from the XML message and add the XML schema location attributes, while copying the data over. The believe the issue is with some French characters. I have changed the encoding to ISO-8859-1, but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns="https://server.net"
     xsi:schemaLocation="schemalocation.net https://server.net/file.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test=". != '' or ./@* != ''">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/@xsi:schemaLocation"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy />
 </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example message: Écrou à ressort de 1/4 pouce, en acier inoxydable type 316, pour profilés et accessoires d’ancrage

Comment: The encoding of the `.xsl` file does not matter, because that is all US-ASCII. But perhaps your `.xml` source file (with the French text in it) has a wrong encoding?

Comment: Hi Heiko, the encoding is not defined on the incoming message.

Comment: If no decoding is declared, the parser may assume UTF-8, but actually it is ISO-8859-1. That could be the problem, try adding `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` to the incoming message.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. When I explicitly set the encoding, everything worked as expected. Thanks so much!